# Trouble using ExcelRange.ToArray<>() in EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus, toarray

I am using EPPlus and don't seem to be able to get the ToArray<> method to work.  I am trying to pull out an array of string variables of column headers in a worksheet.

My code...

```
    public static string[] GetWshHeaders(string WbkNm)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(WbkNm)))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet wsData = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            int noHdrs = wsData.Dimension.Columns;
            ExcelRange hdrs = wsData.Cells[1, 1, 1, noHdrs];
            string[] wsHdrs = hdrs.ToArray<string>();
            return wsHdrs;
        }
    }
```

Intellisense flags the hdrs variable in the line string[] wsHdrs = hdrs.ToArray();.  The message is:  'ExcelRange' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable'.

I have played around with any number of variations of the above code but, well, I wouldn't be posting this question if I had hit upon the correct syntax.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`ExcelRange` has `ExcelRangeBase` as a base class which is declared list this:

```
public class ExcelRangeBase : ExcelAddress, IExcelCell, IDisposable, IEnumerable<ExcelRangeBase>, IEnumerator<ExcelRangeBase>
{
....
}
```

So you are trying to use Linq to do an implicit cast from `IEnumerable<ExcelRangeBase>` to `String[]` which will not work.  You need to use a `Select` to get the `Value` properties of each range object.  And since each `Value` property is of type `Object` you will need to call its `ToString()` method:

```
string[] wsHdrs = hdrs
    .Select(erb => erb.Value.ToString())
    .ToArray();
```

The above will get you the array of strings you are looking for but keep in mind that you are loosing information since `Value` can be a mix of numeric types and string.  Not a problem if you are only interested in, say, simply printing their content.  If you plan to write them back in some way to excel you will have everything as string.